# Using a pointer to an object declared outside a block, inside the block

Tags: objective-c, pointers, compiler-errors, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to use the pointer of an object declared outside an Objective-C block, inside the block itself. For example:

```
NSError* error = nil;
[self invokeAsync:^id{
    return [self doSomething:&error];
}];
```

I get a compiler error on the third line telling me:

> Sending 'NSError *const__strong *' to parameter of type 'NSError
>   *__autoreleasing *' changes retain/release properties of pointer

Why is that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The compiler message is confusing, but is telling you that you have a type mismatch.

But, doesn't matter, because that code makes no sense.

An asynchronous invocation cannot set state in the calling thread's stack.  I.e. there is no way that `error` can be set to a meaningful value.

That is, the method `invokeAsync:` will return before the work block is executed.   Thus, there is no way to return anything meaningful from `invokeAsAsync:` to indicate the success/failure of the execution of the block.

---

If you want to invoke something asynchronously with an error, you'll need a callback:

```
[self invokeAsync:^id{
    NSError *e;
    if ([self doSomething:&e])
        [self errorHappened:e];
    else
        [self asyncThingyDone];
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here. The first is the timing issue which is already pointed out by @bbum.

The other may be what you are asking for, i.e., why the compiler gives such an error. Also as @bbum said, "The compiler message is confusing". In order to decouple the second issue from the first one, let's assume your call is `invokeSyncAndWait:` instead of `invokeAsync:`. Now the timing issue is gone we can focus on the second issue:

```
NSError* error = nil;
[self invokeSyncAndWait:^id{
    return [self doSomething:&error];
}];
```

The `error` variable captured in the block is just a by-value copy, not a real reference:

> Stack (non-static) variables local to the enclosing lexical scope are
>   captured as const variables. Their values are taken at the point of
>   the block expression within the program. In nested blocks, the value
>   is captured from the nearest enclosing scope.

Because you don't have a real reference to the variable `error` in the block, you can not take the address of it. That's why the compiler refuses to compile your code.

To get a by-reference variable, you should use `__block`:

> Variables local to the enclosing lexical scope declared with the
>   __block storage modifier are provided by reference and so are mutable. Any changes are reflected in the enclosing lexical scope, including
>   any other blocks defined within the same enclosing lexical scope.
>   These are discussed in more detail in “The __block Storage Type.”

So the working code is:

```
__block NSError* error = nil;
[self invokeSyncAndWait:^id{
    return [self doSomething:&error];
}];
```

It is still perilous code though:

> Thus, the address of a __block variable can change over time.

I just explained the compiling issue.

Comment: Be wary of the ARC writeback misfeature in clang, which would cause your `error` variable to be nil even when an error occurs. http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=15649#c1